# Getting objects from a rectangular area with fabric.js and draw the area to a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

How can i get fabric.js objects from a specific rectangular area (same behavior as the selection box but manually) then draw the "selected" pixels area of the objects onto a standard canvas?

Note: Getting the pixels data directly is impossible in my case because the canvas is used as a viewport and objects can be out of the viewport (ie: panning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by looking at the function **_collectObjects** and extend fabric.js with a function **drawObjsTo** which gather the objects from a rectangle and render them on a canvas context passed as argument, the solution is a bit dirty but it can solve another problem i had with a simple getImageData on the fabric.js canvas, the resulting data included the selection box, thus the function can also be used to get the pixels data of the objects only.

```
fabric.Canvas.prototype.drawObjsTo = function (ctx, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    var currentObject,
        selectionX1Y1 = new fabric.Point(Math.min(x1, x2), Math.min(y1, y2)),
        selectionX2Y2 = new fabric.Point(Math.max(x1, x2), Math.max(y1, y2));

    for (var i = this._objects.length; i--; ) {
        currentObject = this._objects[i];

        if (!currentObject || !currentObject.visible) {
            continue;
        }

        if (currentObject.intersectsWithRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2) ||
            currentObject.isContainedWithinRect(selectionX1Y1, selectionX2Y2) ||
            currentObject.containsPoint(selectionX1Y1) ||
            currentObject.containsPoint(selectionX2Y2)
        ) {
            currentObject.render(ctx);
        }
    }
};
```

Maybe there should be a way to do that in fabric.js natively.